# Get the percentage of usage for a mount point

Tags: awk, disk-usage

```
[root@vmx ~]# df -h /appl/was  | grep [0-9]%  | awk '{ print $4 }' # => 53%

[root@vmx ~]# df -h /  | grep [0-9]%  | awk '{ print $4 }' # -> 108G
```

This is happening because in case of a long device name, the output is printed on two lines

`[root@vmx ~]# df -h /appl/was 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/appsvg-lvwasapp
                      6.9G  3.4G  3.1G  53% /appl/was`

`[root@vmx ~]# df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       122G  8.1G  108G   7% /`

How can I avoid this?

core-utils version is coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64.

Comment: or use the `df -P` flag

Comment: maybe specific to coreutils versions? 8.23-4 gives 1 "real" line for `df -h /jeff` for /dev/mapper/jeffslongvgnamejeffslongvgnamejeffslongvgnamejeffslongvgname-jeffsreallylonglvnamejeffsreallylonglvnamejeffsreallylonglvname mounted on /jeff

Answer (score 6):

Use `--output` option of `df` command to output only the needed "*percentage*" field:

```
df / --output=pcent | tail -n 1
```

The output:

```
 7%
```

---

> ```
> --output[=FIELD_LIST]
>      use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST
> ```

---

Alternative `df` + `awk` pipeline would look like:

```
df / | awk 'END{ print $(NF-1) }'
7%
```

Comment: [root@el6 ~]# rpm -qf `which df`
coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64
[root@el6 ~]# df / --output=pcent
df: unrecognized option '--output=pcent'
Try `df --help' for more information.

Comment: tail -n 1 will work because the index of the columns is different

Comment: @Spike.WD, run `man df`. Do you see options related to output format?

Comment: @Spike.WD, if you have issues with `df` options - consider my second approach

Comment: The second solution works on el6,el7 and ubuntu 14lts.

Comment: Taken from an edit to the question, « _The following combination works on rhel6,7 and ubuntu 14: `df /appl/wasplg  | awk 'END{ print $(NF-1) }' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g`_ »