# Outputing only number in df command

Tags: debian, disk-usage

I have a disk mounted on /dev/xxx. If I use only `df`, it returns this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xxx       125829120 43861888  81967232  35% /
devtmpfs         4194304        0   4194304   0% /dev
...
```

I need to get only:

a) number of 1K-blocks

b) used space

How to do that?

Comment: You don't want the source device or mountpoint?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369589/117549 and  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424565/117549 for some examples

Comment: You _don't_ have a disk mounted on `/dev/xxx`. You have `/dev/xxx` mounted on `/`.

Comment: @Kusalananda that is what I've figured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
df /dev/xxx | awk 'END { print $2, $3 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df /dev/sda1 --output=source,size,used
```

...gives a terse summary.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk , if you want to do some process inside the block .

For only number of K-blocks and used space :

```
df | awk 'BEGIN { getline } { print $2,$3 }'
```

If you want With Filesystem name :

```
df | awk 'BEGIN { getline }  { print $1,$2,$3 }'
```

For only the disk /dev/xxx

```
df /dev/xxx | awk 'BEGIN { getline }  { print $2,$3 }'
```